# Calculate correlation for discrete-like values from two columns of DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, correlation

Here's the code snippet:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,1,2,2,3,3,3], columns =list('A'))

def m(x):
    if x == 1:
        return 2
    if x == 2:
        return 3
    if x == 3:
        return 1
    return -1
df['B'] = df['A'].map(m)
print df.head(n=10)

   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  2  3
3  2  3
4  3  1
5  3  1
6  3  1
```

As we can see, column B is created by mapping value from column A, thus they should have correlation of value 1, but what I got from below is all not satisfying. Could anyone give me some idea on how to calculate correlation of discrete data for two columns? Great thanks!

```
df['A'].cov(df['B'])
-0.47619047619047611
df['A'].corr(df['B'], method='spearman')
-0.68000000000000016
df['A'].corr(df['B'], method='kendall')
-0.50000000000000011
df['A'].corr(df['B'])
-0.58823529411764708
```

Comment: "thus they should have correlation of value 1": your assumption here is wrong.

Comment: Could you be more specifically? if two columns have correspondance that A->B, B->C and C->A, don't you think there's a correlation between these two columns? @lanS

Comment: There is, but it's not 1. I'm not the best person to explain though. I think you would have better luck asking your question here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Correlation is for linear relationship. What you defined is not linear.

Comment: PS. The correlation would be 1 if your mapping was `x -> x+1`.

Answer (score 1):

The values in the 5th row move in the opposite direction, that's why you  get a  correlation of `-0.58823529411764708`. You can see that in column A the 4th value is 2 and then the 5th value is 3 so your series is increasing in this column. Instead in column B the 4th value is 3 and then the fifth value is 1 so your series is decreasing.  There is no problem with your calculation. If you calculate the correlation til the 4th row you will get a correlation coefficient = 1 because values in both columns move to the same direction.

You can find a nice explanation of correlation in this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29713/what-is-covariance-in-plain-language

Comment: The point is that there's could be scenario with A->B, B->C and C->A, which I intend to dig out the correlation without having to change it manually since I can't see the correlation beforehand.

Comment: By applying the map function in `df[A]` this if statement : `if x == 3: return 1` returns a value for column B that moves in the opposite direction than the value in column A as I explained above. For a down to earth practical example check this [link](http://ci.columbia.edu/ci/premba_test/c0331/s7/s7_5.html)